# Switching from sudo minikube start --vm-driver none to --vm-driver docker and can't access anymore to my apps

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I've just upgrade Minikube 1.7.3 to 1.10.1, and wanted to switch from `--vm-driver none` to `-vm-driver docker`

Everything is working, my apps are deployed, I have no issues, but none of my apps is available, I get:

```
Connection refused
```

when trying to access my APIs from the browser

I use `Traefik` as local Ingress.

with 1.10.1, when I keep using `--vm-driver none` I have no problems.

As I reverted to `--vm-driver none`, I can't give you exact logs, but I could do it with time. What information do I need to debug this issue?

EDIT:

The output for `kubectl get ingress -n influx`

```
measures-ingress              <none>   measures.local               80      4m12s
```

The output for `kubectl get svc -n influx`

```
measures-api-local          ClusterIP   10.97.62.32      <none>        44444/TCP   4m13s
```

the output of `kubectl get po -n influx`

influx        measures-api-local-7fdbdf955-g8k8f           1/1     Running   1          17m

In my config, I have:

Ingress:

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: measures-ingress
  namespace: influx
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
  rules:
  - host: measures.local
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
         serviceName: measures-api-local
         servicePort: 44444
```

Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: measures-api-local
  name: measures-api-local
  namespace: influx
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "44444"
    port: 44444
    targetPort: 44444
  selector:
    app: measures-api-local
  type: ClusterIP
```

Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    reloader.stakater.com/auto: "true"
  labels:
    app: measures-api-local
  name: measures-api-local
  namespace: influx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: measures-api-local
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: measures-api-local
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 0
      containers:
      - image: measures_api:local
        name: measures-api-local
        envFrom:
          - secretRef:
              name: measures-env

      restartPolicy: Always
```

UPDATE: it also happens when I use `minikube start`, and I also have the problem for opensource apps like grafana or pgadmin

Comment: what error you get ? accessing from inside or outside the cluster? logs from traefik pods.

Comment: What do you mean by "None of my apps are available"? You can't access from outside/browser?

Comment: @hariK, Yes, I get a connection refused in the browser

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu I checked traefik logs, and there were no errors

Comment: What's the behavior when you access your application via `kubectl port-forward` or expose it as `NodePort` access via `minikube_ip:NodePort`? Also please share your K8s version

Comment: I edited the question with my service and ingress config, and the result

Comment: add pod yaml as well and output of kubectl describe svc measures-api-local

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu  I added it!

Comment: Its your local env or Cloud env? Did you remove old minikube cluster and started new?

Comment: @PjoterS it's my local env, yes, I wiped my previous minikube cluster

Comment: Just to confirm, after you deleted previous cluster, you have redeployed all apps with all config?

Comment: @PjoterS yep, I redeploy everything. I have a script to do that. When I redeploy using --vm-driver none, everything is ok, but with -vm-driver docker --> connection refused

Comment: @Juliatzin I have exact same situation, did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @volodymyr still running it with none driver

Comment: @Juliatzin Thank you for quick response. I also switched back to vm-driver=none, I saved this question and If I will find a solution I will let you know

Comment: @VolodymyrI. Tx ! The same for me if I succeed to do it