# minikube is not responding anymore when I change local IP - Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.0.78:8443: connect: no route to host

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have a local cluster up and running with Kubernetes.

With COVID, I work now in 2 places, home, and at office.

When I start my local network at home, it will work only at home.

When changing location , I get:

```
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.0.78:8443: connect: no route to host
```

I tried to update context with

```
minikube update-context
```

But it doesn't work.

The only solution that I've found is to drop Minikube and deploy it again

Any idea how to fix it without dropping minikube?

Answer (score 0):

On your host PC, get the IP address of the minikube VM, execute command:

`$ minikube ip`

Sample result - `xxx.yyy.zzz.qqq`

Then create a rich firewall rule to allow all traffic from this VM to your Host:
`$ firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="xxx.yyy.zzz.qqq" accept'`

If you create and delete your minikube VM frequently, you can also allow the whole subnet:

`$ firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="xxx.yyy.zzz.qqq/24" accept'`

Take a look: [minikube-cannot-connect](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2300).

Comment: It didn't work. In fact, now that I am reading again you message, I'm running minikube with the option --vm-drive=none and have no firewall here.

Comment: sudo minikube start --vm-driver none

Comment: I tried to use vm-driver docker, but I have a connection refused error:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61891299/switching-from-sudo-minikube-start-vm-driver-none-to-vm-driver-docker-and-ca