# Impossible to start minikube --driver=none :

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, minikube

I'm trying to boot minikube 1.12.3

here is my script which delete previous cluster, and rebuild a new one, with driver = none.

```
minikube stop
minikube delete
rm -rf ~/.kube
rm -rf ~/.minikube
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/minikube
sudo rm -rf /etc/kubernetes
sudo rm -rf /root/.minikube
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/minikube

#curl -Lo minikube https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/download/v1.11.0/minikube-linux-amd64
curl -Lo minikube https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/download/v1.12.3/minikube-linux-amd64
chmod +x minikube && sudo cp minikube /usr/local/bin/
export MINIKUBE_WANTUPDATENOTIFICATION=false
export MINIKUBE_HOME=$HOME
export MINIKUBE_WANTREPORTERRORPROMPT=false
export CHANGE_MINIKUBE_NONE_USER=true
export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/.kube/config
sudo sysctl fs.protected_regular=0
echo 'Starting Minikube'
sudo minikube start --vm-driver none
sudo cp -r /root/.kube  /root/.minikube $HOME
sudo chown -R $USER $HOME/.kube
sudo chown -R $USER $HOME/.minikube
sed 's/root/home\/julien/g' $KUBECONFIG > tmp; mv tmp $KUBECONFIG
./deploy-local-cluster.sh
kubectl get all -A
```

I tried with v1.11.0 and latest v1.12.3, same result:

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   644  100   644    0     0    921      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   920
100 55.9M  100 55.9M    0     0  1044k      0  0:00:54  0:00:54 --:--:-- 1479k
fs.protected_regular = 0
Starting Minikube
  minikube v1.12.3 on Ubuntu 20.04
✨  Using the none driver based on user configuration
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Running on localhost (CPUs=8, Memory=15768MB, Disk=403863MB) ...
ℹ️  OS release is Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.18.3 on Docker 19.03.3 ...
    ▪ kubelet.resolv-conf=/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
    > kubectl.sha256: 65 B / 65 B [--------------------------] 100.00% ? p/s 0s
    > kubeadm.sha256: 65 B / 65 B [--------------------------] 100.00% ? p/s 0s
    > kubelet.sha256: 65 B / 65 B [--------------------------] 100.00% ? p/s 0s
    > kubectl: 41.99 MiB / 41.99 MiB [---------------] 100.00% 2.44 MiB p/s 18s
    > kubeadm: 37.97 MiB / 37.97 MiB [---------------] 100.00% 2.31 MiB p/s 17s
    > kubelet: 108.04 MiB / 108.04 MiB [-------------] 100.00% 2.55 MiB p/s 43s
  initialization failed, will try again: run: /bin/bash -c "sudo env PATH=/var/lib/minikube/binaries/v1.18.3:$PATH kubeadm init --config /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml  --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube-etcd,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-scheduler.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-etcd.yaml,Port-10250,Swap": exit status 1
stdout:
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.18.3
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
[preflight] Pulling images required for setting up a Kubernetes cluster
[preflight] This might take a minute or two, depending on the speed of your internet connection
[preflight] You can also perform this action in beforehand using 'kubeadm config images pull'
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env"
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
[kubelet-start] Starting the kubelet
[certs] Using certificateDir folder "/var/lib/minikube/certs"
[certs] Using existing ca certificate authority
[certs] Using existing apiserver certificate and key on disk
[certs] Generating "apiserver-kubelet-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "front-proxy-ca" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "front-proxy-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "etcd/ca" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "etcd/server" certificate and key
[certs] etcd/server serving cert is signed for DNS names [suncap localhost] and IPs [192.168.0.45 127.0.0.1 ::1]
[certs] Generating "etcd/peer" certificate and key
[certs] etcd/peer serving cert is signed for DNS names [suncap localhost] and IPs [192.168.0.45 127.0.0.1 ::1]
[certs] Generating "etcd/healthcheck-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "apiserver-etcd-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "sa" key and public key
[kubeconfig] Using kubeconfig folder "/etc/kubernetes"
[kubeconfig] Writing "admin.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "kubelet.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "controller-manager.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "scheduler.conf" kubeconfig file
[control-plane] Using manifest folder "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-apiserver"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-controller-manager"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-scheduler"
[etcd] Creating static Pod manifest for local etcd in "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[wait-control-plane] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests". This can take up to 4m0s
[kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed.

    Unfortunately, an error has occurred:
        timed out waiting for the condition

    This error is likely caused by:
        - The kubelet is not running
        - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)

    If you are on a systemd-powered system, you can try to troubleshoot the error with the following commands:
        - 'systemctl status kubelet'
        - 'journalctl -xeu kubelet'

    Additionally, a control plane component may have crashed or exited when started by the container runtime.
    To troubleshoot, list all containers using your preferred container runtimes CLI.

    Here is one example how you may list all Kubernetes containers running in docker:
        - 'docker ps -a | grep kube | grep -v pause'
        Once you have found the failing container, you can inspect its logs with:
        - 'docker logs CONTAINERID'


stderr:
W0831 16:14:00.080436    6376 configset.go:202] WARNING: kubeadm cannot validate component configs for API groups [kubelet.config.k8s.io kubeproxy.config.k8s.io]
    [WARNING IsDockerSystemdCheck]: detected "cgroupfs" as the Docker cgroup driver. The recommended driver is "systemd". Please follow the guide at https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/cri/
    [WARNING Swap]: running with swap on is not supported. Please disable swap
W0831 16:14:03.620507    6376 manifests.go:225] the default kube-apiserver authorization-mode is "Node,RBAC"; using "Node,RBAC"
W0831 16:14:03.621143    6376 manifests.go:225] the default kube-apiserver authorization-mode is "Node,RBAC"; using "Node,RBAC"
error execution phase wait-control-plane: couldn't initialize a Kubernetes cluster
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
  Suggestion: Check output of 'journalctl -xeu kubelet', try passing --extra-config=kubelet.cgroup-driver=systemd to minikube start
Related issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/4172
error: no configuration has been provided, try setting KUBERNETES_MASTER environment variable
```

`systemctl status kubelet` gives me

```
 ~ systemctl status kubelet
● kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
             └─10-kubeadm.conf
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-08-31 16:19:07 CEST; 5min ago
       Docs: http://kubernetes.io/docs/
   Main PID: 10709 (kubelet)
      Tasks: 27 (limit: 18856)
     Memory: 36.0M
     CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
             └─10709 /var/lib/minikube/binaries/v1.18.3/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml --container-runtime=docker --hostname->

août 31 16:19:32 suncap kubelet[10709]: I0831 16:19:32.273438   10709 trace.go:116] Trace[1414212595]: "Reflector ListAndWatch" name:k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:46 (started: 2020-0>
août 31 16:19:32 suncap kubelet[10709]: Trace[1414212595]: [23.913950998s] [23.913950998s] Objects listed
août 31 16:19:32 suncap kubelet[10709]: I0831 16:19:32.273445   10709 trace.go:116] Trace[588997321]: "Reflector ListAndWatch" name:k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:135 (started: 2020-08-31 16:19:1>
août 31 16:19:32 suncap kubelet[10709]: Trace[588997321]: [17.71221973s] [17.71221973s] Objects listed
août 31 16:19:32 suncap kubelet[10709]: I0831 16:19:32.273200   10709 trace.go:116] Trace[1548512050]: "Reflector ListAndWatch" name:k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:526 (started: 2020-08-31 16:>
août 31 16:19:32 suncap kubelet[10709]: Trace[1548512050]: [23.913290464s] [23.913290464s] Objects listed
août 31 16:19:32 suncap kubelet[10709]: I0831 16:19:32.275257   10709 trace.go:116] Trace[297760465]: "Reflector ListAndWatch" name:k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:135 (started: 2020-08-31 16:19:1>
août 31 16:19:32 suncap kubelet[10709]: Trace[297760465]: [17.729370638s] [17.729370638s] Objects listed
août 31 16:19:32 suncap kubelet[10709]: I0831 16:19:32.276218   10709 kubelet_node_status.go:73] Successfully registered node suncap
août 31 16:19:32 suncap kubelet[10709]: I0831 16:19:32.392414   10709 reconciler.go:157] Reconciler: start to sync state
```

And `journalctl -xeu kubelet` give me:

```
➜  ~ journalctl -xeu kubelet
août 31 16:19:28 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:28.180248   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:28 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:28.280545   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:28 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:28.380782   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:28 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:28.481114   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:28 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:28.581371   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:28 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:28.681727   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:28 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:28.782152   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:28 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:28.882459   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:28 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:28.982818   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:29 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:29.083231   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:29 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:29.183551   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:29 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:29.283780   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:29 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:29.384088   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:29 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:29.484271   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:29 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:29.584574   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:29 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:29.684845   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:29 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:29.785118   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:29 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:29.885491   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:29 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:29.985768   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:30 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:30.086080   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:30 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:30.186390   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:30 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:30.286594   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:30 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:30.386941   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:30 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:30.487156   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:30 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:30.587494   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:30 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:30.687708   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:30 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:30.787877   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:30 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:30.888133   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:30 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:30.988426   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:31 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:31.088730   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:31 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:31.189120   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:31 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:31.289307   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:31 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:31.389486   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:31 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:31.489734   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:31 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:31.590167   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:31 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:31.690352   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:31 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:31.790667   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:31 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:31.890909   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:31 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:31.991140   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:32 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:32.091484   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:32 suncap kubelet[10709]: E0831 16:19:32.191872   10709 kubelet.go:2267] node "suncap" not found
août 31 16:19:32 suncap kubelet[10709]: I0831 16:19:32.273200   10709 trace.go:116] Trace[828480946]: "Reflector ListAndWatch" name:k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:517 (started: 2020-08-31 16:1>
août 31 16:19:32 suncap kubelet[10709]: Trace[828480946]: [23.913514726s] [23.913514726s] Objects listed
août 31 16:19:32 suncap kubelet[10709]: I0831 16:19:32.273438   10709 trace.go:116] Trace[1414212595]: "Reflector ListAndWatch" name:k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:46 (started: 2020-0>
août 31 16:19:32 suncap kubelet[10709]: Trace[1414212595]: [23.913950998s] [23.913950998s] Objects listed
août 31 16:19:32 suncap kubelet[10709]: I0831 16:19:32.273445   10709 trace.go:116] Trace[588997321]: "Reflector ListAndWatch" name:k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:135 (started: 2020-08-31 16:19:1>
août 31 16:19:32 suncap kubelet[10709]: Trace[588997321]: [17.71221973s] [17.71221973s] Objects listed
août 31 16:19:32 suncap kubelet[10709]: I0831 16:19:32.273200   10709 trace.go:116] Trace[1548512050]: "Reflector ListAndWatch" name:k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:526 (started: 2020-08-31 16:>
août 31 16:19:32 suncap kubelet[10709]: Trace[1548512050]: [23.913290464s] [23.913290464s] Objects listed
août 31 16:19:32 suncap kubelet[10709]: I0831 16:19:32.275257   10709 trace.go:116] Trace[297760465]: "Reflector ListAndWatch" name:k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:135 (started: 2020-08-31 16:19:1>
août 31 16:19:32 suncap kubelet[10709]: Trace[297760465]: [17.729370638s] [17.729370638s] Objects listed
août 31 16:19:32 suncap kubelet[10709]: I0831 16:19:32.276218   10709 kubelet_node_status.go:73] Successfully registered node suncap
août 31 16:19:32 suncap kubelet[10709]: I0831 16:19:32.392414   10709 reconciler.go:157] Reconciler: start to sync state
```

I have no clue what to do! Anyone can help me debug this ?

EDIT: When I run `minikube start` it will work.

Now, thing is when I run `minikube start` or `minikube start --driver=docker` all deployments and pods are OK, but I cannot reach any of them: [Switching from sudo minikube start --vm-driver none to --vm-driver docker and can't access anymore to my apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61891299/switching-from-sudo-minikube-start-vm-driver-none-to-vm-driver-docker-and-ca)

Comment: Did you manage to find solution ?

Comment: nop, I didn't...

Comment: If running minikube start somehow solve this particular problem please post it as an answer and then wait for another issue you have raised -  why you cannot access pods to be solved on different site.

Answer (score 0):

Is also there so i did - minikube delete and after that minikube start ... it worked
Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).